# What are the in_features and out_features supposed to be?

Tags: pytorch

`torch.nn.Linear(in_features, out_features, bias=True, device=None, dtype=None)`

I have a dataset of [914,19] shape. should my in_features be 914? And I want to predict 5 different values so should my output feature be 5?

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(914,512)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512,512)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(512,512)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(512,5)
        

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear3(x))
        x = self.linear4(x)
        
        return x
NeuralNet = NeuralNetwork()
print(NeuralNet)
```

Comment: 19 in-features and 5 out-features. 914 is the number of training samples you have, which can be split into batches for training.

Answer (score 1):

Your input data is shaped `(914, 19)`, assuming *914* refers to your batch size here, then the `in_features` corresponds to *19*. This can be read as a tensor containing *914* *19*-feature-long input vectors.

In this case, the `in_features` of `linear1` would be set to `19`.

Comment: Thank you very much. What would be the preferrable size of the hidden layer?

Comment: I can't tell, it will depend on your dataset size and type. Ultimately, you have to experiment with different sizes. Start with a simple model and overfit your data, then scale up to generalize better to the validation set.